# JMeter, MSSQL, JDBC, and Integrated Security with sqljdbc_auth.dll

Tags: jdbc, jmeter, mssql-jdbc, integrated-security

Notwithstanding [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33252076/jmeter-database-testing/33265067#33265067), I still have not determined the error in my configuration causing the JMeter JDBC sampler to reject integrated security.

- Downloaded the SQL Server JDBC package for x64 and installed mssql-jdbc-9.4.1.jre8.jar in JMETER_PATH\lib.
- Installed mssql-jdbc_auth-9.4.1.x86.dll in JMETER_PATH\lib, too, but, as advised on the Blazemeter comments, I also installed it in C:\windows\system32, since it is on my java.library.path.
- Restarted JMeter.

Still getting the error in the Response:

```
Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (This driver is not configured for integrated authentication. ClientConnectionId:9c225a40-362d-4aba-8339-cfab9270048f)
```

JMeter version is 5.4.1.

Updating with screenshot showing `os.arch`, `java.library.path`, and placement of the DLL.
Database URL: jdbc:sqlserver://myservername:1433;integratedSecurity=true

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add a [Debug Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script/) to your Test Plan and configure it like:

   [image]
2. Look for [`os.arch` property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10846105/all-possible-values-os-arch-in-32bit-jre-and-in-64bit-jre), it should be `amd64` or `x86_64`, if it isn't - geta 64-bit Java SDK
3. Look for [`java.library.path` property](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-library-path-what-is-java-library-and-how-to-use/), copy the `mssql-jdbc_auth-9.4.1.x64.dll` library to one of the folders which are in the `java.library.path`
4. Restart JMeter to pick up the .dll
5. Make sure that `integratedSecurity=true` stanza is in your [JDBC URL](https://www.baeldung.com/java-jdbc-url-format) like

   ```
   jdbc:sqlserver://somehost:1433;integratedSecurity=true
   ```

Comment: Followed these steps.   I got the 64-bit SDK as shown above.      

Yesterday, I had put the DLL in the path shown on the added screenshot.  I started JMeter today and tried again.

Comment: I cannot support you if you're not paying any attention to my instructions. Your screenshot says that you're using 32-bit JDK, why you're trying to load 64-bit dll?

Comment: Because in your answer, line #2, you said "it should be amd64 or x86_64, if it isn't - get a 64-bit Java SDK".   I was following that instruction, since the property, in fact, was neither.   But now I see I could have figured out what you meant.

Comment: Finally worked, but ONLY after putting the DLL in the FIRST folder in the java.library.path list.     Putting it in c:\windows\system32 did *not* work.   So it matters which folder - it can't be just any one.